# What do the options of component "Joomla! Update" mean?

Tags: administrator

In the options of the component `Joomla! Update` you can specify the update server. The current help info doesn't provide enough information to decide to use `Custom URL` and `Currently configured (no change)`. When to use those options?

Comment: See docs.joomla.org for introduction on Joomla. If this question is not clear you are on the wrong q&a.

Comment: To be honest, the bloody exclamation mark confused the way I read your question.

Comment: Can't help that. It is the name of the component. Should I put the component name between quotes?

Comment: I think so, at least for me it would make more sence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Custom URL` option in the `Update Server` dropdown allows you to set the update server (or more specifically, an XML file listing update locations) in the `Custom URL` field below. This could be useful in a number of scenarios:

- If you centrally manage multiple Joomla sites and want to stop users from performing updates, you could point it to a dummy file.
- If you have your own in-house Joomla distribution mechanism (perhaps to stop users from upgrading to versions you don't support, or to point to a custom Joomla version you've modified yourself), you can point it to your own XML manifest of available updates, much like [this example](http://update.joomla.org/core/extension.xml).

The `Currently configured (no change)` option stops Joomla from receiving / seeing any updates (a terrible name if you ask me).

Find out more in the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Help32%3aComponents_Joomla_Update).

Comment: Pointing to a dummy file is a nice idea :)

Comment: Would probably use ACL permission to control who is allowed to update!

Comment: That's valid - I imagine the `Custom URL` option gets very little usage, and the more I think about it the more I imagine it's designed for very specific use cases (e.g. custom version distribution, pushing specific versions that are 'corporate approved', etc.)

Comment: Maybe for language specific versions or providers that have installation/update software.

Comment: In J3.4 the Update Server is now called Update Channel, LTS is renamed Default, STS renamed Next. The No change option has been removed. Extension manager->Update Sites allow management, disable Joomla! Core to simulate the No change option. Suggest to verify other sites to enabled as well.